# Play a succession of swf using javascript

Tags: jquery, html, flash, media-player

I would like to play a succession of swf: initialy, play the first one; when this one is over, i'd like to play the second etc... All without using Flash (to play some swf compilated yet).

I searched in jQuery plugins but I didn't find something which could be ok. Something like:

```
    $("#my_swf").flash( src="..." params:... callBack function (when swf over): function(){
    read_the_next_swf();
});
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.
Thank you !

Comment: Just curious, why do you not want to use flash to implement the chain?

Comment: It would be easier to manipulate... I want to have the possibility to add as many swf as I want, by admin interface (URLs of swf stocked in database)

Comment: I think the only way of knowing when a swf is done is from within Flash, see my comment below. You can load an easy to edit xml file that stores which swfs to load in your desired order. Once you set it up in flash all you would have to do is edit the xml to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have some kind of control over the flash you are playing = how do you know when a piece of flash is finished?

See [Detecting when a Flash file has finished playing in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719322/detecting-when-a-flash-file-has-finished-playing-in-javascript)

AFAIK it cant be done.

Comment: I was thinking external interface as well, but at that point why get javascript involved when the rest can be handled in Flash with just a few more lines of code.

Comment: Yeah I'll maybe do an AS3 player which detect how many swf there are, and play the chain... Thank you guys.